# How to change cell format on load time in DevExpress Winform

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I want to change cell formatting, cell value, alignment at time of cell loading in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/3048/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Formatting/How-to-Format-Display-Text-in-Grid-s-Cells-Depending-on-Values-in-Other-Cells

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
using System.Globalization;

// The cultures used to format the values for the two different currencies. 
CultureInfo ciUSA = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo ciEUR = new CultureInfo("fr-FR", false);

private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e) 
{

    ColumnView view = sender as ColumnView;

    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Price" && e.ListSourceRowIndex != DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
    {
       int currencyType =   (int)view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "CurrencyType");
       decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value);
       switch (currencyType)
       {
         case 0: e.DisplayText = string.Format(ciUSA, "{0:c}", price); break;
         case 1: e.DisplayText = string.Format(ciEUR, "{0:c}", price); break;
       }
    }
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [devexpress](/questions/tagged/devexpress)